# Delete element with javascript by onload

Tags: javascript, html

helo here is a code:

```
<a id="sdffg" href="/allgemeinen/me-libe-love-y/"><p class="erfg" class="quotes">
bla bla bla
</p></a>
```

i want to delete `a` element
js code for it:

```
    <script>
    window.onload=function(){

var btn = document.getElementById('sdffg');
btn.onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('txt').remove();
    this.remove();
};

}

    </script>
```

but it is not working, page:

```
https://geburtstagsplanet.com/allgemeinen/me-libe-love-y/
```

my js code is really in source code but it is not working:

```
view-source:https://geburtstagsplanet.com/allgemeinen/me-libe-love-y/
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('txt')` You have no `#txt` element anywhere. You also need to `preventDefault` in the handler to prevent link clicks from redirecting the page.

Comment: What your code says is that, when I click the element with the ID `sdffg`, remove the element with the ID `txt` from the page. But, neither your sample code and your actual website have the element with the ID `txt`.

Comment: I think what you want to do is remove this element `<a id="sdffg"...` when the page loads, is that it?

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
   window.onload=function(){
      const element = document.getElementById("elementor-icons-fa-solid-css");
      element.remove();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer after 4 years and 3 months

Answer (score 0):

You can already put `onclick` directly on your `a` tag like this:

```
<a id="sdffg" href="/allgemeinen/me-libe-love-y/" onclick="this.remove()">
```

Also based on your question you wanted to delete the element on `onload` then it must be:

**Javascript:**

```
window.onload=function(){
    var elem = document.getElementById("sdffg");
    elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
}
```

you can also use **jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sdffg").remove();
});
```

Comment: it doesn't work:
http://geburtstagsplanet.com/allgemeinen/me-libe-love-y/

Answer (score 0):

Problem: #txt doesn't exits in the DOM,
Best guess is you want to delete #sdffg from the dom

```
window.onload=function(){

var btn = document.getElementById('sdffg');
btn.onclick = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.body.removeChild(this);
};
```

This should help.